# Removing index.php on MAMP

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter, mamp

this questions was asked before and has had many responses. The problem is nothing i tried worked.

Background: i use MAMP and all of my web project are located under WebProjects which I relocated out of its standard location within the MAMP folder in Applications. so my structure is something like this:

**Documents/WebProjects/GreatSite/Application/...**

What happened so far: my understanding is that removing index.php can be done either through httpd.conf or .htaccess. anytime i touched httpd.conf, Apache refuses to start. I tried various edits to .htaccess including the one in codeigniter.com/wiki/mod-rewrite and the last one from a post on SO which is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this give me the following error when i access the site:

*An Error Was Encountered

Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.*

I have updated config.php to have $config['index_page'] = '';  and i have placed the .htaccess file in the GreatSite folder.

One other note, my CI system folder is up a level from GreatSite. Not sure if this has any impact. also, apache has the module loaded.

so, I'm hoping someone has successfully done this on MAMP and could provide direction specifically around the content of their .htaccess (or even httpd.conf), it's location and any other mods they had to make to get this going.

**update**

and trying to access a controller using http://localhost:8888/greatsite/account rewrites the url as http://localhost:8888/greatsite/account/index and gives 2 errors:
Message: Undefined index: scaffolding_trigger
Filename: libraries/Router.php
Line Number: 164

and

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/djeetee/Documents/DevProjects/system/libraries/Exceptions.php:166)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 662

hope this helps.

thanks

Comment: what do you have in config/route.php? also `.htacsess` file should go wherever your `index.php` resides...also have you deleted or renamed the `welcome` controller?

Comment: .htaccess is in the same folder as index.php. the welcome controller is no longer there and was replaced by one called main which works fine to take the user the homepage of the site which works fine btw when i'm not trying to get rid of index.php through .htaccess. The content of route.php is this:  
$route['default_controller'] = "main";  
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";  does the location of the CI system folder have anything to do with all this?

Comment: the [wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) article should work...All my CI installations use it, I just have to modify the **RewriteBase** (third line)...for you it might be something like `/greatsite/`

Comment: the wiki code produce error 500 - internal server error :( the weird thing is that although the site is working with the shorter .htaccess file, my javascript ajax post code i was working on 2 days ago now will only work if i include index.php before the name of the controller Arggggg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess does not have to reside in the same folder as index.php. You can do

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

for instance. Just make sure you have the correct RewriteBase and then correct path to your index.php and that the rewrite module is enabled in apache.

Comment: still no luck. using http://localhost:8888/greatsite gives the same error An Error Was Encountered
Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.  I will edit the main question with more details.

Comment: is your RewriteBase set to /greatsite/? does the site work if you skip the rewrite stuff?

Comment: ok now it working. my mistake. i edited config.php last nite added some comments and did not close them hence the 'default route' error i mentioned and that's why your suggested RewriteRule did not work earlier. so to recap i updated my .htaccess to include /greatsite/index.php and all is good - i think ;) thanks for your help

Comment: true, htaccess is not necessary to be placed in the same folder, it's just me that always have it on the root of my project which always the same for `index.php`